# can anyone explain the math behind the red ship in this simple game? [homing missile esque]

Tags: java, android, actionscript, andengine, trigonometry

the game is a little flash component found here:
http://www.rydeman.com/erik/skepp2.html

i found that link here:
http://board.flashkit.com/board/archive/index.php/t-175556.html

I have been using/converting the examples they give in the second link but cant get my "missile" to behave correctly. I am using java and andEngine combo. Here is what I have right now:

```
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
            int Missile_speed=20;

            int dx=(int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getX()-(face.getWidth()/2));
            int dy=(int) (pSceneTouchEvent.getY()-(face.getHeight()/2));

            double distance=Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));

            //dx/=distance;  /** not really sure what " /= " is on this line and the next **/
            //dy/=distance;

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //to do
            }

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {

                face.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(1, face.getX(), (int)(dx/distance)*Missile_speed, face.getY(),(int)(dy/distance)*Missile_speed, EaseQuadOut.getInstance()));
            }

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                //to do
            }
            return true;            
            }
```

this code just makes the object travel to the upper right hand corner of the screen and it doesnt move after that. so i am missing something

my end goal is to have an object that will chase the users touch coordinates. I know how to have the object follow such coordinates but I dont want it to follow the exact path, but rather the shortest path to the most updated coordinates. so more like an intercept course

thank you

Comment: `foo /= bar` is the same as `foo = foo / bar`

Comment: i kind of think my problem is with using vectors. i think i need to define a vector for use with Math.sqrt. Im going to research this but if anyone cares to answer please and thank you

Comment: No you don't *need* to use vectors. dx and dy already define a vector. Working with vectors is good to make your life easier (you could for example just do 'double dist = delta_vector.Length()' instead of calculating it with Math.sqrt). But the end result is the same, and the important thing first is understanding WHY, and not HOW.

Answer (score 4):

dx and dy start with the distances in x and y to your target position (I guess you figured out that much, but bear with me)

When you divide dx or dy by the distance, you now have those values constrained between 0 and 1, and these values tell you where it is relation to that axis, without regard to distance (example: if the target is exactly to the right, no matter how far or close, dx/dist is 1 and dy/dist is 0).

Now when you multiply Missile_speed by those axis, the missile will chase that direction in it's maximum speed.

Those values between 0 and 1 are the cosine of the angle between the target position and the missile, btw (it's important that you visualize this so you can think through similar problems in these terms on your own in the future).

I'm not sure this is what you wanted - it seems you wanted the trigonometry of the situation explained and not working code, so that's what I tried to do (not sure if I succeeded). Really understand this, and you should have no problem with similar problems in the future (and these situations are *really* ubiquitous in game development, btw)

Comment: sorry for the late response, ive been refreshing my memory on some of these equations, once I have the vector and multiply by missile speed, how do i apply that to the missile coordinates to have it move towards the target? i understand what you are saying a lot more now you spelled it out, but i guess im still not sure how to finish the job

Comment: i dont know if this is what i wanted but IT IS what i needed. thank you